# Data do not update in Table when i close the MS Access and reopen it

Tags: vba, ms-access

I use the below query to add records in table using Form and it works perfectly when i write it first time but when i close the MS Access and reopen the file to add new data via form, the data is not updated in table and it do not show any error.

```
Private Sub cmdsave_Click()
    CurrentDb.Execute "Insert into tblcosting(Reqsht, Cost) " & " Values(" & Me.txtreqsht & ", " & Me.txtcost & ")"   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting a message "The macros in this project are disabled" it would explain why it is not working. To enable, go to File|Options|Trust Center|Trust Center Settings|Trusted Locations, and add the location where the database is located. When you re-open the database, VBA code, such as that for your command button, will now be able to run.

Regards,

Comment: Did this solve your issue? If so, please mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the structure of tblcosting. Most likely there is a violation of its properties.
You can check the error message by creating the same query and running it.

```
Private Sub cmdsave_Click()
    Dim strsql as String

    strsql= "Insert into tblcosting(Reqsht, Cost) " 
    strsql = strsql & " Values(" & Me.txtreqsht & ", " & Me.txtcost & ")"

    Debug.Print strsql

End Sub
```

Copy the query from the immediate window and paste it in a new query (select the SQl view). Then run the query to check what is causing the issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for prompt reply, actually i am new to use MS Access. I just copy paste your coding in VBA code window in event procedures but nothing happened. can you help me how to select SQl view.

Comment: You have to open the Immediate Window to see the results of Debug.Print strsql. You can find it in the VBA editor under the View menu. The make a new query. You will be in the structure view. To change to SQL view select the dropdown control on the top left, just beneath the File menu.

Comment: Thanks. it is showing an error "The macros in this project are disabled".

Comment: Please post the structure of the table, any validation rules and the SQL of the query.

Comment: In the table i have 3 fields. ID (Auto number), Reqsht (Number) & Cost (Currency). There is no validation rules i set, and no query. Simply i created form with 2 fields Require sheets & cost. one button to save data in the table. when first i created everything was fine and data was also saving.

Comment: So do you have just one record in the table? What happens if you insert a record manually?